# Phase shift of the annihilation operator when passing through a dielectric

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, experimental-physics, quantum-optics, dielectric

Let's say there is a plane electromagnetic wave with annihilation operator $\hat a$. Why is it the case that when this beam passes through a transparent dielectric slab of some finite thickness, it transforms as $\hat a \rightarrow e^{- \iota \theta} \hat a$?. I suspect it has got something to do with the change in optical length caused by introducing the dielectric, but can't figure out how that change will cause the phase shift.